# Want to remove [echo], [script] like keywords from file

Tags: ant

I am using filter in a filterchain, in a task which supports the filterchain element, i.e. the built-in Concat, Copy, LoadFile, LoadProperties, Move tasks.

So, for example, copy or move the file using a filterchain containing your linecontains filter.

Use the negate parameter on your linecontains filter to exclude lines containing that string.

Example: Consider the following code

```
<project default="test">
    <target name="test">
        <copy tofile="file.txt.edit" file="file.txt">
            <filterchain>
                <linecontains negate="true">
                    <contains value="[echo]"/>
                </linecontains>
            </filterchain>
        </copy>
    </target>
</project>
```

---

```
outputs:

$ cat file.txt
[echo] Your project1 location is: D:/Project/Project1
[echo] Your project2 location is: D:/Project/Project2
[script] my script running
[echo] Your project3 location is: D:/Project/Project3
[echo] Your project4 location is: D:/Project/Project4

$ cat file.txt.edit
[script] my script running

Expected:
$ cat file.txt.edit
Your project1 location is: D:/Project/Project1
Your project2 location is: D:/Project/Project2
[script] my script running
Your project3 location is: D:/Project/Project3
Your project4 location is: D:/Project/Project4
```

Here if i am using filterchain then complete line gets deleted. I want only the word like
[echo], [script]...etc. should be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `linecontains` element with [`replaceregex`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#replaceregex):

```
<tokenfilter>
    <replaceregex pattern="\[echo\]" replace="" />
</tokenfilter>
```

For multiple token replacements, modify `pattern="\[(echo|script)\]"`